# Show that $f$ is not continuous at $x = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

> Consider the function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with
>   $$f(x) = 
> \begin{cases}
> x &\text{ if } x \text{ is rational} \\
> 1 &\text{ if } x \text{ is irrational} 
> \end{cases}$$ Show that $f$ is not continuous at $x=0.$

Here is what I showed.  I was wondering if I could get some clarity that my work is correct or incorrect.

Note $f(0)=0.$

Consider $X_n = \sqrt{2}\frac{1}{n+1} \to 0$

Have $f(X_n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N = 1 \neq f(0) = f(\lim X_n)$

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct.

Comment: Would that be enough to write as the proof? @Mr. X

Comment: Yes because continuity and sequential continuity are same here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good proof, but you may want to not have to assume knowledge that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.
One way to do that is to use the $\epsilon,\delta$ definition, and consider any interval $[0,\epsilon]$. If $\epsilon$ is rational, then assuming some irrational number $\alpha$ exists, we have that for any $\delta$, $$f\left(\frac{\alpha\epsilon}{\lceil\alpha\rceil}-0\right)=1> \left|\frac{\alpha\epsilon}{\lceil\alpha\rceil}-0\right|$$
Showing that the function cannot be continuous.
If $\epsilon$ is irrational, simply use $f(\epsilon/2)=1$.

Comment: I am a little confused on this definition.  How does this show sqrt(2) is irrational?  My book does not go over epsilon delta ideas that much.

Comment: @buizmath - it doesn't, that's the point. In this proof you don't actually need a concrete irrational number.

Comment: Oh I Read Your suggesting incorrectly. Im confused on why i dont need a concrete  irrational number? I based all my work off a proposition about discontinuous functions in my book. I may not be understanding the concepts then.